# How swap big to host int8 number?

Tags: objective-c, c, endianness

I work with binary protocol, so it's normally to use:

```
int32_t number = SOME_NUMBER;
CFSwapInt32BigToHost(number);
```

But what's about int8_t?

Comment: A byte does not need swapping. Only quantities > 1 byte have endianness.

Comment: @PaulR so I should use:
    (*(int8_t*)[dataSession bytes]);
right?

Comment: A cast is usually a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - try it without first and see if you get an error or warning. If nothing then carry on, otherwise understand the error or warning, try to fix it properly, and only use a cast as a last resort if all else fails.

Comment: If I didn't use cast, then I getting: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'const void *' from a function with result type 'int8_t' (aka 'signed char')

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to pass this to a function which expects a non-const parameter - you should probably fix the function signature and make this a const parameter, but it's hard to tell without seeing the actual code.

Comment: OK - it looks like the cast *might* be the only way in this case - it's hard to tell though because your code is in a comment, where `*` is interpreted as mark-up for *italics* - use backticks (`) to quote code to prevent this happening (just one backtick at the start and another at the end).

Comment: `- (int8_t)int8FromDataWithStartIndex:(NSUInteger)indexByte;
{
    NSData *dataSession = [self subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexByte, 1)];
    return (*(int8_t*)[dataSession bytes]);
}`

Comment: OK - yes, I don't think you can easily avoid the cast in this case.

Comment: @PaulR thank you for your help yesterday and today. I totally understand situation around Bytes now. SO is greatest resource for us, developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianess usually refers to the order of bytes. Since every byte has its own address, a multi-byte word can be ordered in two (or more, but typically it has big-endianness or little-endiness) different directions, higher byte higher address or lower byte higher address. So you need a byte swap.

Bits are not addressable. So there is no need to deal with endianness. And even if there is a operation that indexes a bit, nobody would be that crazy to make the bit 0 the most significant. So you do not need a bit swap.